# For loop errors on call

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop

I have the following code

```
List<WorkingRecord> recordListz = new List<WorkingRecord>();

-----other unrelated code----------

recordListz = IF_Export(out ifRecCount,out WrittenRecords);

for (int i = 0; i < recordListz.Count; i++)
{
//do something
}
```

recordListz is created ok (well sort of but more on that later), the IF_Export method retuns the list ok and then if I put the breakpoint on the for loop and hover over the recordListz object it looks fine (with 10 records in it) and the count reports 10 records too. However as soon as I try to execute the loop the code errors claiming "Object not set to instance of an object" (non of the objects in the list are null). Plus if I put a quick watch on the object at this point it claims the value is ['' is null].

Now on to the issue with creating the recordListz object in the first place.... There is actually some other code (completely unrelated to the code above) between the instantiation of recordListz and the method call. Originally I had the following code

```
List<WorkingRecord> recordListz = IF_Export(out ifRecCount,out WrittenRecords);
```

However this resulted in an error of "Object not set to an instance of an object", even though the method being called returned a perfectly fine list (confirmed by placing a breakpoint on the return line of the method).

I then broke it out to the following

```
List<WorkingRecord> recordListz = new List<WorkingRecord>();
recordListz = IF_Export(out ifRecCount,out WrittenRecords);
```

However this errored on the first line with "Object not set to an instance of an object". I have exactly the same line which is called in the IF_Export method which works fine and is in the same class as the code calling it...

Moving the line to the top of the code stopped this from erroring, but this then results in the loop error.

What on earth is going on, I have never seen this before.

-----------------------UPDATE-------------------

Ok if I have the following code

```
-----other unrelated code----------
List<int> WrittenRecords=new List<int>();
List<WorkingRecord> recordListz = new List<WorkingRecord>();

recordListz = IF_Export(out ifRecCount,out WrittenRecords);

for (int i = 0; i < recordListz.Count; i++)
{
//do something
}
```

The recordListz instantiation line errors with "object not set to instance of an object

However if I have the following code

```
-----other unrelated code----------
List<WorkingRecord> recordLista = new List<WorkingRecord>();
List<int> WrittenRecords=new List<int>();
List<WorkingRecord> recordListz = new List<WorkingRecord>();

recordListz = IF_Export(out ifRecCount,out WrittenRecords);

for (int i = 0; i < recordListz.Count; i++)
{
//do something
}
```

Then recordListz instantiation still errors, but recordLista instantiation works fine!

Plus if I have the following code

```
-----other unrelated code----------
List<int> WrittenRecords=new List<int>();
List<WorkingRecord> recordLista = new List<WorkingRecord>();
List<WorkingRecord> recordListz = new List<WorkingRecord>();

recordListz = IF_Export(out ifRecCount,out WrittenRecords);

for (int i = 0; i < recordListz.Count; i++)
{
//do something
}
```

recordLista also works fine!

--------Another Update------

If I put in the following code

```
-----other unrelated code----------
List<int> WrittenRecords=new List<int>();
List<WorkingRecord> recordLista = new List<WorkingRecord>();
List<WorkingRecord> recordListz = new List<WorkingRecord>();

recordLista = IF_Export(out ifRecCount,out WrittenRecords);

for (int i = 0; i < recordLista.Count; i++)
{
//do something
}
```

It is now recordLista instantiation that errors..........

--------Update 3---------------

Ok, I have found at which point the strange things are happening.

The code sits inside an if statement

```
if (dsExportRecords != null && dsExportRecords.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
```

dsExportRecords is a dataset. If I put my code immediately within the if statement then the strange things happen, however if it is immediately before the if statement then everything is fine.

Comment: can you post the code of IF_Export?

Comment: what is `recordListz` immediately after the `IF_Export` call? is it perhaps `null`? Note that the `new List<WorkingRecord>()` won't ever be used unless the `------other unrelated code-------` uses that list somewhere.

Comment: @Marc Gravell. recordListz is populated with 10 records after the call to IF_Export, As I said if I break on the for loop it is still populated and has a count of 10, it is only when the loop actually executes that it somehow becomes null.

Comment: @Elior. The code for IF_Export is huge, but the important thing is that if I break on the return statement the object Returned is a List<WorkingRecord> with 10 records in it. Also I assume this method is not the problem as the List will not instantiate before this method is even called (unless as I said, I put it much earlier in the code)

Comment: @coolblue2000 and are the 10 things in there all non-null? a list can contain 10 nulls, for example... or 7 non-null records and 3 nulls. A `for` loop will not magically wipe a variable to `null`. Are you **very sure** that list is non-null at the return? as in: have you used a breakpoint, assert, or other technique to verify this?

Comment: @Marc Gravell. Yes all the items are non null. Yes absolutely certain that the list is non null at the return and absolutely certain that it is not null on the breakpoint set on the for loop.

Comment: @coolblue2000 then sorry to disappoint, but the problem has to be somewhere in the `// do something`

Comment: @Marc Gravell. Ok then take a look at the question update above. This gets even more strange......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sort of found the issue (well my code now works anyway)

The issue turned out to be some Linq code.

The loop which was failing was as follows

```
for (int i = 0; i < recordLista.Count; i++)
{
    int id = (from r in WrittenRecords where r == recordLista[i].RequestID select r).FirstOrDefault();
    if (id != 0)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

WrittenRecords is a `List<int>`

The ling line never got hit (as the loop failed as soon as I stepped into it), so this never looked like the problem. However it was indeed the issue. Not sure why this line also stopped code far above it from working too (ie instantiating the recordLista List) but it did indeed cause issues all over the place.

The actual problem was that the WrittenRecords integer list was returned as an empty list (not null, but had no items) and although before entering the loop WrittenRecords did report to be an empty list once the try catch had caught the error it then reported it as Null which is still baffling me..... However as I never need this code to run if there are no items in the list, putting an if statement around the for loop to only allow it to run if WrittenRecords contains items seems to have solved the issue.

I however still have no idea why the loop failed to execute at all, why the linq code failed with what was simply an empty list, why the empty list suddenly turned into a null list on the catch or indeed why the error thrown by linq stated that it was null or why the linq code stopped the recordLista from being instantiated at all. But at least my code now works.